# I can't input a double number

Tags: java, exception

```
enter code here package com.company;
```

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static double min (double n1 , double n2 , double n3)
{
    double  minNumber = n1;
    if (minNumber>n2)
        minNumber=n2;

    if (minNumber>n3)
        minNumber=n3;

    return minNumber;
}
public static double max (double n1 , double n2 , double n3){

    double  maxNumber = n1;
    if (maxNumber<n2)
        maxNumber=n2;

    if (maxNumber<n3)
        maxNumber=n3;

    return maxNumber;}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1 if you want minimum \nEnter 2 if you want maximum \nEnter 3 if you want to stop the program");
        byte Enter = input.nextByte();
        if (Enter==1) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter first number");
            double x = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            double y = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter third number");
            double z = in.nextInt();
            double min = min(x,y,z);
            System.out.println("the minimum number is :" + min);
        }
        else if (Enter == 2) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter first number");
            double x = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            double y = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter third number");
            double z = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("the maximum number is :" + max(x, y, z));
        }
        else if (Enter==3){
            break;
        }
        else System.out.println("Enter again");
    }
}
```

}
/* output is :
Enter 1 if you want minimum
Enter 2 if you want maximum
Enter 3 if you want to stop the program
1
Enter first number
12.3
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:39)

```
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to use any IDE on a beginner stage of learning Java, which will save lot of time and will give compile-time error on the fly

Answer (score 1):

You need write `in.nextDouble()` instead `in.nextInt()`